# delink picture hyperlinks

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to delink the pictures from excel sheet using vba but could not find a solution to this.

Found below link but it is for shapes and charts and does not work with pictures inserted as links:-

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/convert-linked-excel-charts-to-embedded-ones/357bb64d-b852-4e43-8671-b0f49f0dabc3

Answer (score 0):

An image is still a Shape. Share your code as maybe you are missing an error. **If it is a simple image with a HyperLink** then try this

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1")).ShapeRange.Item(1).Hyperlink.Delete
```

**Otherwise do the following** - go to the Developer tab and click Record Macro. Next remove the Hyperlink manually from an image and then stop the Record Macro by hitting it again. Then go to the VBA Project and see the resulting code to remove the Hyperlink.

Comment: I tried ActiveDocument.Shapes.Item(1).Hyperlink.Delete but it does not work. I am also unable to find a way to delink the image manually.
The image is linked and the image does not contain Hyperlink so when I go to Hyperlink I cannot find the file location.

Comment: Please check the name of the shape and try my code with the name. If possible share your workbook

Comment: I am adding the link, it contains the vba content 

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32394002/my%20pics.xlsm

Comment: The images in the attachment are correctly referenced by the macro I presented above (ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1"))), however, there are no hyperlinks attached to them - hence.there is nothing to delete

Comment: As I said in my comments, the images are added as "link to file" and the images does not contain hyperlinks. This is why the image is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 4 different ways that might work, none is perfect, so try it in debug mode

```
err.clear
on error resume next 'everything not working will throw an Error
with activesheet.shapes("Picture 1") 
    .type=13 'forcfully changing the type form a linketype to normal picture, might not work
    .linkformat.autoupdate = false 'might not work
    .hyperlink = false 'might not work
    .formula = VbNullString 'might not work

    'if all fails try the last hope (copy it but no link)
    .copy 'if fails : ActiveSheet.Pictures.Paste link:=True
    'activesheet.Pictures.Paste link:=True 'failed (works only for picture copy of ranges ?)
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Picture (Enhanced Metafile)"
    'you can save .top and .left in a single variable and replace the new pic on the right place
    Dim X as single, Y as Single
    X=.left
    Y=.top


    with activesheet.shapes(activesheet.shapes.count) 'the new pic is the last in shapes collection
    'same result but i like it less, with : selection.shaperange.item(1) ' you need to be in the picture's sheet, wich in our case is ok because we work on activesheet
         .top=Y
         .left=X
         .name = "Picture 1"
     End with
     .delete 'removes the old picture
End With
```